# How to write 'select query' for finding difference between debit of one account and credit of another account using one table only?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Sql statements:

```
SELECT debit,credit FROM transactionentries where glaccountid = 15374;
SELECT debit,credit FROM transactionentries where glaccountid = 15376;
```

Hint: the `debit` for this glaccountid, `15374` must be equal to the `credit` for other glaccountid, `15376` and vice verse.

What i am trying to get is to return transaction entries where the debit of one account is not equal to the credit of the other account.

Any help ?

Thanks in advance.

My attempt:

```
SELECT debit,credit FROM transactionentries 
where glaccountid = 15374 
and debit not in (
  SELECT credit FROM transactionentries where glaccountid = 15376
);
```

Query above returns no rows and i expect to return transaction entries where the debit of one account is not equal to the credit of the other account.

Comment: First of all, Your query is working fine. It is returning the record of a transaction made by `glaccountid = 15374`. Also, @Littlefoot 's query is not giving the expected output. See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9f2f00bfb597b9ead048fe073342c676)

Answer (score 0):

Self cross join might help.

```
SQL> with transactionentries (glaccountid, debit, credit) as
  2    (select 15374, 100, 200 from dual union all     -- different: 100 <> 101 and ...
  3     select 15376, 201, 101 from dual union all     -- ...        200 <> 201
  4     --
  5     select 1, 1000, 2000 from dual union all       -- same: 1000 = 1000 and ...
  6     select 2, 2000, 1000 from dual                 ...      2000 = 2000
  7    )
  8  select a.glaccountid, a.debit a_debit, b.credit b_credit,
  9         b.glaccountid, b.debit b_debit, a.credit a_credit
 10  from transactionentries a cross join transactionentries b
 11  where a.glaccountid = 15374
 12    and b.glaccountid = 15376
 13    and (   a.debit <> b.credit
 14         or b.debit <> a.credit
 15        );

GLACCOUNTID    A_DEBIT   B_CREDIT GLACCOUNTID    B_DEBIT   A_CREDIT
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
      15374        100        101       15376        201        200

SQL>
```

If values in lines #11 and #12 are modified to 1000 and 2000, query won't return anything because those values match.

Though, that's impractical approach as you must know `a` and `b` pairs whose debits and credits should match. If there's something you could use to automate it, use it.

Answer (score 0):

select * from transactionentries s
      where not  exists ( select 1 from transactionentries p
      where p.debit=s.credit
      and s.debit=p.credit);